# Ionic Capacitor FileSystem fileExists

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have some pictures stored on /src/assets/img/.
Now I want to check if an image exists. If yes I want to display it, else I want to display a placeholder img.

I tried

```
async checkFile(strPath: string)
{
    let contents = await Filesystem.readFile({
        path: strPath,
        directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data,
        encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
    });
    console.log(contents);
}
```

Call:

```
checkFile('/assets/img/kategorien/image.jpg).then(function ...
```

But it doesn’t work. The file is not found. How do I have to set the path/directory for it to work?

Comment: You should use FileSystem to work with the *files on the device.* Here you are just accessing your app asset file. You can just set a reference to the file location. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @arif08 I want to check if a img in assets exists and if not I wann to display another. How could I do this without cordova?

Comment: You control what goes in the assets folder or not. So you should know if an image exists in the assets folder. This is static. But if you insist, you can use `onerror` which basically fires when an image fails to load.

Comment: OnError is what I searched. Thank you!